# Sublime Text 3 Custom Layout

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I want a custom layout for my ST3 - specifically, I want this layout structure.
Can someone tell me how can I do it ?[image]

Comment: Here's my [Layouts.sublime-commands](https://gist.github.com/mattst/64c8f3d7fbb0a7be27f38f05afb4a300) file which adds all the layouts from the `View --> Layout` menu to Sublime Text's Command Palette as well as all 4 possible combinations of 3 pane layouts. Save the raw [Layouts.sublime-commands](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mattst/64c8f3d7fbb0a7be27f38f05afb4a300/raw/1f46a0955ca966895265e9e92c1200b5063b5c9d/Layouts.sublime-commands) file to your Sublime Text config `User` folder (or elsewhere if you know what you're doing). To use open the Command Palette and type `Set Layout...`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although you can get your hands dirty with manually creating such a layout, probably the easiest way to pull this off would be to use a package to do it. The [Origami](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Origami) package is one example of this.

Using that package, you can follow the following steps to get the layout that you're interested in:

1. Select `Origami: Create Pane Below` command (or use the standard `View > Layout > Rows: 2` menu item) to create two rows
2. Focus the bottom pane and select `Origami: Create Pane on the Right`

Once you have this layout complete, you can use `Origami: Save Current Layout` from the command palette to save it and then easily recall it later as needed.

---

Assuming that you don't want to/can't install third party packages, you can also make your own customized menu item and/or key binding that will set this layout for you.

In order to add a new item to the menu, save the following text as `Main.sublime-menu` in your `User` package (use `Preferences > Browse Packages` if you don't know where that is):

```json
[
    {
        "caption": "View",
        "mnemonic": "V",
        "id": "view",
        "children":
        [
            { "caption": "-", "id": "groups" },
            {
                "caption": "Layout",
                "mnemonic": "L",
                "id": "layout",
                "children":
                [
                    {
                        "caption": "Three Pane",
                        "command": "set_layout",
                        "args":
                        {
                            "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0 ],
                            "rows": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0 ],
                            "cells": [
                                [0, 0, 2, 1 ],
                                [0, 1, 1, 2 ],
                                [1, 1, 2, 2 ]
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

This will add a new menu entry under `View > Layout` called `Three Pane` which, when selected, will set your desired layout. Alter the value of the `caption` string as appropriate to change the name of the layout.

Additionally, you can add the following key binding to your custom key bindings (`Preferences > Key Bindings` from the menu) in order to have a hot key that does the same thing:

```json
{
    "keys": ["alt+shift+3"],
    "command": "set_layout",
    "args":
    {
        "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0 ],
        "rows": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0 ],
        "cells": [
            [0, 0, 2, 1 ],
            [0, 1, 1, 2 ],
            [1, 1, 2, 2 ]
        ]
    }
},
```

If this is your first custom key binding, make sure to wrap this entire text in a pair of `[` and `]`, as the key bindings are a list of items and this represents just the key binding itself.

This reuses the default Windows/Linux key binding for three columns, so you can change that as appropriate. If you do this in combination with the menu change above, the menu will automatically display the key binding you're using as a reminder in case you forget.

For reference, the `set_layout` command takes the same `layout` argument as the (officially undocumented) `window.set_layout()` API call. There is [unofficial documentation on that method](https://docs.sublimetext.io/reference/python_api.html#window-set-layout) that explains how this works, although here I cheated and used Origami to create the layout.

Comment: Hello, i need to do it mannualy because i cant download package manager, can you help me?

Comment: It's not `Main.sublime.menu` but rather `Main.sublime-menu`.

Comment: @certainlyakey thanks for the heads up, not sure how I missed that. :)

Answer (score 3):

#### 1st Option:

Install the package more layouts and press  ALT + SHIFT + 6

Here you can see the package and some example of a lot of layouts:

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/More%20Layouts

Example with my sublime text 3:[image]

If you dont know how to install packages here you can find out how:

https://packagecontrol.io/installation

#### 2nd Option:

Open the console using CTRL + `

And type this command:

`window.set_layout({'cols': [0.0, 0.5, 1.0], 'cells': [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1], [0, 1, 2, 2]], 'rows': [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]})`

That should do the trick for that exact layout.

Comment: Hello, i need to do it mannualy because i cant download package manager, can you help me?

Comment: I found this step by step guide to do what you want
Please tell me if this is what you want and I will add it to the answer
https://nikolaloncar.com/sublime-text-custom-layout-tutorial-inside-out-with-examples/

Comment: yesterday i tried that tutorial but not didnt work, if you have another tut or if you know to to do it, please post the answer, thanks

Comment: Check my 2nd option, I made the dirty work for you :)

Comment: Thats what i want it, thank you, one las question, how can i place this layout in the view menu?, everytime i need this layout i need to put this code?

Comment: Se my answer for a menu entry and associated key binding.

Comment: Well he was faster!.

Answer (score 0):

I made a diagram for me to understand how `set_layout` constructs a layout from the values given to it, and figured I'd share.
[image: diagram]
Yes, X really is `cols` and Y really is `rows`. That is unintuitive.

Think of it like this: the vertical lines (columns) grow from points in the horizontal axis, and the horizontal lines (rows) grow from points in the vertical axis.

I hope it's understandable and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I tried hard to understand the logic behind the number of the set_layout command.

So here my explanation + a few examples:

```json
  {
    "keys": [""],
    "command": "set_layout",
    "args": {
      "cols": ["startposition of column in percent", "next positition of column  in percent", "endposition of column  in percent"], 
      "rows": ["startposition of row  in percent", "next position of row  in percent", "endposition of row  in percent"], 
      "cells": [ //each cell array is one pane
        ["startposition of column", "startposition of row", "endposition of column", "endposition of row"], 
      ]
    }
  },

  { // 1 top pane, 2 split (left/right) bottom panes
    "keys": ["alt+4"],
    "command": "set_layout",
    "args": {
      "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0], //offers 2 columns 
      "rows": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0], //offers 2 rows
      "cells": [ //each array is one pane
        [0, 0, 2, 1], //first pane: starts at column 0 (0.0 left) and ends at column 2 (1.0 right) and also start at row 0 (0.0 top) and ends at row 1 ( 0.5 mid)
        [0, 1, 1, 2], //second pane: starts at column 0 (0.0 left) - and ends at column 1 (0.5 mid) and also starts at row 1 (0.5 mid) and ends at row 2 (1.0 bottom)
        [1, 1, 2, 2], //third pane: starts at column 1 (0.5 mid) and ends at column 2 (1.0 right) and also start at row 1 (0.5 mid) and ends at row 2 (1.0 bottom) 
      ]
    }
  },

  { // 1 left pane, 2 split (bottom/top) right panes
    "keys": ["alt+5"],
    "command": "set_layout",
    "args": {
      "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0], //offers 2 columns
      "rows": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0], //offers 2 rows
      "cells": [ //each array is one pane
        [0, 0, 1, 2], //first pane: column 0 - 1, row 0 - 2
        [1, 1, 2, 2], //second pane: column 1 - 2, row 1 - 2
        [1, 0, 2, 2], //third pane: column 1 - 2, row 0 - 2
      ]
    }
  },

  { // 2 split (left/right) top panes, 2 split (left/right) bottom panes
    "keys": ["alt+6"],
    "command": "set_layout",
    "args": {
      "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0], //offers 2 columns
      "rows": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0], //offers 2 rows
      "cells": [ //each array is one pane
        [0, 0, 1, 1], //first pane: column 0 - 1, row 0 - 2
        [0, 1, 1, 2], //second pane: column 0 - 1, row 1 - 2
        [1, 0, 2, 1], //third pane: column 1 - 2, row 0 - 2
        [1, 1, 2, 2], //fourth pane: column 1 - 2, row 1 - 2
      ]
    }
  },

  { // 3 split (left/right) top panes, 3 split (left/right) bottom panes
    "keys": ["alt+7"],
    "command": "set_layout",
    "args": {
      "cols": [0.0, 0.33, 0.66, 1.0], //offers 3 columns
      "rows": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0], //offers 2 rows
      "cells": [ //each array is one pane
        [0, 0, 1, 1], //first pane: column 0 - 1, row 0 - 2
        [1, 0, 2, 1], //second pane: column 1 - 2, row 1 - 2
        [2, 0, 3, 1], //third pane: column 1 - 2, row 0 - 2
        [0, 1, 1, 2], //fourth pane: column 0 - 1, row 0 - 2
        [1, 1, 2, 2], //fifth pane: column 1 - 2, row 1 - 2
        [2, 1, 3, 2], //sixth pane: column 1 - 2, row 0 - 2
      ]
    }
  },
```